# Sample to get texel color from opengl texture for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, c

How to get value of texel color from OpenGL texture ? I want get pixel value of a texture to check whether its transparent or not.

Comment: Are you using fixed pipeline or shaders (OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0)?

Comment: I am using fixed pipeline

Comment: [glReadPixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880487/read-pixels-from-off-screen-opengl-pixel-buffer-in-ios-oopengl-es), [but that only works for framebuffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863416/read-texture-bytes-with-glreadpixels)